# gradle finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My project contains 3 libraries: **calendar_cmcc**,**Wheel_library** and **yellowPage_lib**.

I can build the project perfectly, but gradle throws an error when I run it.Here is the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/jim/tools/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

gradle file list:

**app's** build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {

            compileSdkVersion 21
            buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "cn.com.geartech.app"
                minSdkVersion 17
                targetSdkVersion 19
                versionCode 100 //from 20 to 21
                //cmcc0000522 is 26
                //0608 is
                // 27
                //0615 is 27
                //0616 is 27
                //1.2.20 36
                versionName "1.2.26.10"
                multiDexEnabled = true
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }

                debug {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.deb
                }
            }
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            }
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
                }
            }
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
            compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
            compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.0.3@aar'
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            compile files('src/main/libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/pinyin4j-2.5.0.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-with-sources.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/zxing.jar')
            compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
            compile files('src/main/libs/cmcc-sso-sdk.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/cmcc-sso.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/cmcc_enc.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/AOE_20140617_001.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/sync_sdk_ydyjyxgh_20150304.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/fastjson-1.2.5.jar')
            compile project(':yellowPage_lib')
            compile project(':Wheel_library')
            compile project(':calendar_cmcc')
            compile files('src/main/libs/pinyin4j.jar')
            compile files('src/main/libs/gcordSDK.jar')
        }
```

build.gradle of **calendar_cmcc**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 17
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
        compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
        compile 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.6'
        compile('com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.9.6') {
            exclude group: 'org.jsoup', module: 'jsoup'
            exclude group: 'org.freemarker', module: 'freemarker'
            exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
        }
        compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.6'
        compile files('lib/httpclient-android-4.3.5.2-davdroid1.jar')
        compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
            exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
            exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
        compile files('libs/android-common-chips.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-common.jar')
        compile files('libs/calendar-common.jar')
    }
```

build.gradle of **Wheel_library**:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    }
```

build.gradle of **yellowPage_lib**:

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 21
            buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 8
                targetSdkVersion 19
            }

            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
            compile files('libs/BaiduLBS_Android.jar')
            compile files('libs/YellowPage_SDK.jar')
        }
```

Now, All I kown is that the error was cause by **calendar_cmcc's** build.gradle file.When I change 'compile' to 'provided' of dependencies from **calendar_cmcc's** build.gradle , it runs fine.

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
        compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
        compile 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.6'
        compile('com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.9.6') {
            exclude group: 'org.jsoup', module: 'jsoup'
            exclude group: 'org.freemarker', module: 'freemarker'
            exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
        }
        compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.6'
        compile files('lib/httpclient-android-4.3.5.2-davdroid1.jar')
        compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
            exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
            exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
        compile files('libs/android-common-chips.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-common.jar')
        compile files('libs/calendar-common.jar')
    }
```

changed to

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
        provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
        provided 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.6'
        provided ('com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.9.6') {
            exclude group: 'org.jsoup', module: 'jsoup'
            exclude group: 'org.freemarker', module: 'freemarker'
            exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
        }
        compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.6'
        compile files('lib/httpclient-android-4.3.5.2-davdroid1.jar')
        compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
            exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
            exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
        compile files('libs/android-common-chips.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-common.jar')
        compile files('libs/calendar-common.jar')
    }
```

but it will cause another error:

```
07-24 15:54:41.991   32166-1373/cn.com.geartech.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DefaultTimeZoneRegistryFactory', referenced from method at.bitfire.davdroid.resource.Event.<clinit>
    07-24 15:54:42.001   32166-1373/cn.com.geartech.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder', referenced from method at.bitfire.davdroid.resource.Event.TimezoneDefToTzId
    07-24 15:54:42.021   32166-1373/cn.com.geartech.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'net.fortuna.ical4j.util.UidGenerator', referenced from method at.bitfire.davdroid.resource.Event.generateUID
    07-24 15:54:42.061   32166-1373/cn.com.geartech.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder', referenced from method at.bitfire.davdroid.resource.Event.parseEntity
```

It seems that the **org.mnode.ical4j**  can't be package in the apk when the gradle build.

I have search the answer on the stackoverflow for many days,but it can't works.
So,how should I do? Help,please!thanks！

Comment: I have solved it by myself.When your project contains too many files, Android studio will throw a problem:finished with non-zero exit value 3.It's a limit for Android studio, but not for intellij idea.So, just add:dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }    to your app.gradle files, and it will work fine.Possibly, after fixed the problem we talk about above.It will cause another problem:not found ***.jar or ***.class files.It should be the 65k method problem, so you shuld look this link:https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I re-post the answer of jim.zhang here: 
(since the first time I view this question, I missed zhang's comment)

Add below configure in build.gradle file.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And possibly，It will cause another problem :not found ***.jar or ***.class files.It should be the 65k method problem, so you shuld look this link: developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I did the same try adding:

android {
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
 }
}

into build.gradle.

Thanks @Anh-Tuan Mai