# Android Error: Your app has more methods references than can fit in a single dex file

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, gradle

Gradle Build is successful but when I try to run my app, I get this error:

> Error:Your app has more methods references than can fit in a single
>   dex file. See
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

I got this after I implemented 'Sign-in using Google Account' feature to my app.

Why am I getting this? I don't understand the problem in order to fix this. Do any of you have a solution for this?

**EDIT**

I Followed the steps, however it's showing another error:

> Copying resources from program jar [/Users/Earthling/AndroidStudioProjects/GoogleTestProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/debug/jars/1/1f/combined.jar]
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471772/how-to-shrink-code-65k-method-limit-in-dex/28018547#28018547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `multidex` because your projet exceeds the limit of methods authorized in one app (it's about ~56000 or almost, I don't remember). See this quote in Documentation (the link you provided by the way):

> As the Android platform has continued to grow, so has the size of Android apps. When your application and the libraries it references reach a certain size, you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture.

In order to build and run, you have [to configure your `build.gradle`](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) as follows:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        // enabling multidex
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

// add the dependencie
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Then, create your own `Application` class as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this); // install multidex
    }
}
```

Finally, add this class in the `Manifest`:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name=".MyApplication">
```

Or you can just use the `android.multidex.application` by default instead of creating one like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Comment: Followed these steps but I got this new error though. EDITED the question

Comment: @Earthling, you'd try to follow this [answer/comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605291/gradle-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-3#comment51487848_31605291). It might resolve your issue.